# Private variable assigned in function but not outside

Tags: c++, class, variables, private

I have a class User() with private variable string friends. friends is set in function addFriend() and returned in function getFriends().

```
class User
{
    public:
        User();
        void setName(string username);
        void addFriend();
        string getFriends();
        string getName();
     private:
        string name;
        string friends;
};

User::User()
{
    friends = ",";
}

void User::setName(string username)
{
    name = username;
}

void User::addFriend()
{
    string friendName;
    cout << "Enter friends name: ";    //inputs "Bob"
    cin >> friendName;
    cout << endl;

    friends += friendName + ",";
    cout << getFriends() << endl;   //this outputs ",Bob,"
}

string User::getFriends()
{
    return friends;
}

string User::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

The addFriend() function behaves how it should in that when a friend is added to the friends list, they are separated by commas. When I call the getFriends() function inside of the addFriend() function, it behaves as expected. However, when I try to call user.getFriends(); I get nothing but a comma (",").

```
class System
{
    public:
        System();
        void createUser();
        User& getCurrentUser();
        vector<User> users;
    private:
        User currentUser;
};

System::System() {}

void System::createUser()
{
    string username;
    bool userExists = false;

    cout << "Please enter a user name: ";

    cin >> username;   
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
    {
        if(users.at(i).getName() == username)
            userExists = true;
    }

    if(!userExists)
    {
        User temp;     //creates a temporary user stored in vector of Users 
        users.push_back(temp);      //puts new User at end of users

        users.back().setName(username);

        currentUser = users.back();
    }

    if(userExists)
        cout << "User already exists." << endl << endl;
}

User& System::getCurrentUser()
{
    return currentUser;
}
```

The system class can call other unspecified functions in User() without issue.

```
int main()
{
    System system;
    system.createUser();                  //create user named "Bill"
    system.getCurrentUser().addFriend();  //inputs "Bob"

    for(int i = 0; i < system.users.size(); i++)
    {
        string buddies = system.users.at(i).getFriends();
        cout << "User: " + system.users.at(i).getName();
        cout << " - Friends: " << buddies << endl;
    }
}
```

This outputs only a comma. Why is this?

Edit 1: Language is C++.

Edit 2: I have left out a majority of the code for the sake of simplicity on what I thought was the problem. I am now adding a class, its functions, and its interactions with User().

Comment: Might depend on what language this is.

Comment: Works fine for me. http://ideone.com/9R2WBI

Comment: Works fine for me too. http://ideone.com/CWoNOf

Comment: Works fine for me too, Microsoft compiler...

Comment: Edited adding more code. I left out a lot for simplicity's sake. But clearly there was not an issue in the small section I included.

Comment: Er... You add friends to the `currentUser` object. You never add friends to `User` objects stored in `users` vector. And you print friends from `users` vector. No wonder they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Because this:-

```
  private:
      User currentUser;
```

`currentUser` isn't a pointer or reference, it's an actual `user` object. So making changes to it via `addFriend` won't have any effect on the `user` object in the vector.

Comment: expanding on this , you should get rid of `currentUser`, and make the `getCurrentUser` function do `{ if ( users.empty() throw std::runtime_error("No current user");  return users.back(); }`